# WordPress home page 404 HTTP Code, but content is sending correctly ?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress installation. The problem that I have is the following:

The home page while served normaly, content, images, HTML, anything are served correctly the HTTP Status Code is 404. Any other page is served with normal HTTP Status 200. The only page that served with 404 is the home page.

Any idea on how to solve that problem please ? :?

Comment: What URL are you using to call the home page?

Comment: what are you talking about ? In example, if my domain is that : http://www.my-domain.ext/ when I enter manualy that address to my browser the HTTP Status 404. If I go to page http://www.my-domain.ext/some/post/name I get HTTP Status 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. We solved the problem.

For some reason the mod_secure made that problem. We disabled it just for check and we found that was the problem !!!

Thanks a lot all of you !